# Django hide field when creating new object

Tags: python, django

I want to hide field name when user is creating new object, but it must be visible if user wants to edit this object. 
I tried exclude method but it makes field invisible when i try to edit this field. for example i want to hide status field.

```
class Toys(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='Item_tags')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: One way to do it is hiding using CSS using class names

Comment: i want to hide this field in django admin panel. any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the model admin that you register in your `admin.py` file you can overload the `get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs)` method. As you can see it takes the obj argument, it is `None` only on add (not `None` on change).
From there you could mess around with the form to exclude the form field "name" from it only if the `obj is None`.

In Django 1.10 that method is in `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.get_form`.

**EDIT 1** (**this is by far not the best solution**)
I can't give you a full solution here, but you can start with something like:

```
# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin

from models import Toys


class ToysModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        # all the code you have in the original
        # django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.get_form
        # up to the last try except

        if obj is not None:
            defaults['fields'] = ('tags', 'price', 'status', )

        try:
            return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
        except FieldError as e:
            raise FieldError(
                '%s. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class %s.'
                % (e, self.__class__.__name__)
            )

admin.site.register(Toys, ToysModelAdmin)
```

**EDIT 2** (**this is a better example**)

```
# admin.py

from collections import OrderedDict

from django.contrib import admin

from models import Toys


class ToysModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # this is not perfect as you'll need to keep track of your
    # model changes also here, but you won't accidentally add
    # a field that is not supposed to be editable
    _add_fields = ('tags', 'price', 'status', )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        model_form = super(ToysModelAdmin, self).get_form(
            request, obj, **kwargs
        )

        if obj is None:
            model_form._meta.fields = self._add_fields
            model_form.base_fields = OrderedDict(**[
                (field, model_form.base_fields[field])
                for field in self._add_fields
            ])

        return model_form
```

Comment: can you show me by example. i edited my question with example

Comment: Check out my EDIT 2, I briefly tested it, I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: one problem it ordering field names by alphabet how can i fix it?

Comment: I don't understand, you wan't the ordered alphabetically or not? This is an `OrderedDict` the order of the fields is set once a key is set in it. To change that order you'll may want to redefine the `model_form.base_fields`. For a mroe complex solution you'll have to ask another question as it's not really related to this thing.

Comment: it ordered fields names alphabetically, but i want to stay them as they were ordinary.

Comment: i have this error "type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list"

Comment: Did you copy this line correctly? `(field, model_form.base_fields[field])`

Comment: @I.Jokhadze This error is because you must not use `**` operator when creating OrderedDict Replace `OrderedDict(**[(field, mode...` -> `OrderedDict([(field, mode`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I wanted to exclude some columns only in create form.

You can override `get_exclude()` method

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

@admin.register(models.Toys)
class ToysAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_exclude(self, request, obj=None):
        exclude = list(super().get_exclude(request, obj) or [])
        if obj==None:
            # columns to exclude when it's create form
            exclude += ["status","column_to_hide_on_create"]
        return tuple(set(exclude))
```